# Having problems changing an img of a pre-made html

Tags: html

I am making a simple website for my dad's store.  He does delivery for his grocery store to the local area through phone calls.  He now wants to do through a website to make it more convenient for his customers.  I copied pre-made template and have been changing things for his needs.  I am almost done but one thing has been giving me problems.

I want to change the background img of one of the pics, the template used but I cannot figure out where the img is mentioned in the code at all.  Then as a experiment, I moved the pic out of the folder and the website holder was blank showing that the img is being called upon.  Then I put the img back and it started working normally again.

```
<h5><a id="OrderT"></a></h5>
            <section class="reservation-area section-gap relative">
                <div class="overlay overlay-bg"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 reservation-left">
                            <h1 class="text-white">Preorder or Delivery </h1>
                            <p class="text-white pt-20">
                                Here you can make your order either for pickup or delivery.  If you are asking for delivery, we ask that at the end of the order, you place your address there.  Pickup means you plan to come by and we will have your order ready for a quick payment instead of looking around for what you want.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5 reservation-right">

                            <form name="contactform" method="post" action="email.php">
<table width="450px">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name"></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" placeholder="Name*" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="51" required>
 </td>
</tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email"></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" placeholder="Email*" name="email" maxlength="80" size="51" required>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone"></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" placeholder="Number*" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="51" required>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="order"></label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="order" required placeholder="Order*" style="width:400px; height:150px;" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">   <a href="email.php"></a>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>                 
</section>
```

Right now, there is an img of a pizza but this is a grocery store and my dad does not sell pizza so I wanted to change that.  Just been looking at this code for a while and just not sure how this even works.

Comment: I might have missed something but i dont think the image comes from this html

Comment: options: image is loaded as background-image css (check css files for image name) or this html is loaded inside another html (by iframe etc) and the image is provided from  somewhere else

Comment: the css part is more likely

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: to find the neccesary css file check at the top of your current html file there should be a tag saying <head> in which another tag saying style should be ,search for a style element that has a file with .css at the end and isnt a complete url - then search for it in your server files if you find the css file search for the image name in it and repalce it with your (not pizza :() image path/name

Comment: Thank you guys.  Yeah, so I did not realize there was a css files to check around.  Was able to finally change it and sorry for the late reply ><.